# Simplify ReturnType for union of multiple functions from an object

Tags: typescript

I have an object of functions, and I need to create a type that is the union of what they return. A simple example:

```
const actions = {
  success: () => true,
  count: () => 0,
};
```

Now, I want to create the corresponding type. This can be done via:

```
type AvailableValues = ReturnType<typeof actions.success | typeof actions.failure>;
```

This works, but it's very verbose -- chiefly having to write `typeof actions` repeatedly.

`Pick<typeof actions, 'success' | 'failure'>` is close, but the type it generates is an object rather than the union of function return types, so I'm sort of back to where I started.

Is there any way to extract multiple return types simultaneously?

See a setup example here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhsKBLcEYF4YG8BQMYQCuwwAphBAFwwAUAlBgHwxQBOhpANHjKIWFGr0mMAAzcAvgG4cOKAE8ADqRgBBAG5wkAGzgAjbaQBqcbRzSYASqSiFWYACpLSAHgXKQAM3iIUkAHREJORoAD4szl4+yKj+fAKMUkA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `actions` had some non-functions in there or if you need to manually specify `"success"` and `"count"` for some reason (maybe there are other functions that you *don't* want the return types of), then you can do this by using a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) to get the function types at the `"success"` and `"count"` keys, like this:

```
type AvailableValues = ReturnType<(typeof actions)['success' | 'count']>
```

A lookup type is the bracket notation where given a type `T` and a key type `K` (or a union of keys) then the property type at that key (or union of property types at those keys) is `T[K]`.

---

If you want to get a union of the return types for *all* function-valued properties of an object type in general, you can write it like this:

```
type ReturnTypesOfFunctionProps<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : never
}[keyof T];
```

Note that `T[K] extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : never` is using [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) and is basically the same as `ReturnType<T[K]>` (see [library definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1524)) except that `ReturnType` constrains its input.

And then for your type it yields the same thing:

```
type AvailableValues2 = ReturnTypesOfFunctionProps<typeof actions>;
// type AvailableValues2 = number | boolean
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhsKBLcEYF4YG8BQMYQCuwwAphBAFwwAUAlBgHwxQBOhpANHjKIWFGr0mMAAzcAvgG48OKAE8ADqRgBBAG5wkAGzgAjbaQBqcbRzSYASqSiFWYACpLSAHhoLlIAGbxEKSHQA2gDkRCTkEMEwAD4wwXwCwQC6jDgA9GkszmqaOvqGJmbkGDBghAC2eqSsMTB6ICCGcGA4ctnWtvZOyhAA8l4AYvx+4AAKrCCKEC4OzJi4+IEA0jBIYDAA1qTy3jAOSdQOy0kwpAAeUKRgACZoNAB0j3CsAOZU8GDyDOjMa17VMEsMAA-ICYNQwKR1NUcBJAlsdj59jI2soclpdAZjKZzAAmEodOyOZx9QbDZBjCZTFweUi7BAUyCMGQZLJojQY-LYooQfGYMqVAGxeqNUjNIA)

Comment: Can you explain what the `infer` syntax does?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
type Actions = typeof actions;

type AvailableValues = ReturnType<Actions[keyof Actions]>
```